# Posting an Object with AJAX, CodeIgniter CSRF Enabled

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This is in CodeIgniter

Here's the relevant Javascript:

```
var tx = $("tx"+working_row).val;
var mods = $("mods"+working_row).val;
var pos = $("pos"+working_row).val;
var startdate = $("startdate"+working_row).val;
var enddate = $("enddate"+working_row).val;
var fordx = $("4dx"+working_row).val;
var qty = $("qty"+working_row).val;
var price = $("price"+working_row).val;
var token = $.cookie("csrf_cookie_name")
var obj = {"csrf_token_name": token, "tx" : tx };
$.post("index.php/auth/fee_schedule",obj, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

If I remove the "tx":tx from the obj variable it works just fine, but anytime I add anything to that object it returns error 500, not allowed. I'd like to get all 9 variables into that object, but at the moment, can't even get one to work, so where's my typo/screw up/mis-understanding?

Any Suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling the `val()` method properly, should be:

```
var tx = $("tx"+working_row).val();
```

Comment: You sir are a saint. Ever have one of those days you stare at something knowing there's a problem and can't see it! This was me for the last 2 hours!

Comment: totally, that's what firebug is for, it will normally yell at you for stuff like this : ) Welcome to SO, you can mark my answer as accepted by hitting the check mark.

Comment: I will as soon as I'm allowed. apparently there's a timelimit before I can accept it! I was actually looking at it in Firebug and it wasn't throwing any errors except the post response, is there something I'm missing to make it check Jquery syntax or something?

Comment: depends on the type of error I guess, it should have told you that val is not a valid property of element, but if it didnt that's probably why you missed it.